# What do I have to type in my .bashlogin to hide my computer and home directory?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-leopard

If I open my Terminal app in Mac OS X it looks like this

```
tabalugas-macbook:~ tabaluga$
```

I want to customize this shell, so the Username tabaluga won't show up. The Shell should look like this

```
mymacbook:~ hello$
```

what do I have to type?

Answer (score 4):

```
PS1="mymacbook:\w hello$ "
```

See the PROMPTING section of `man bash`

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it looks now like this

tabalugas-macbook.local:~ hello$ 

any Idea how to convert the "tabalugas-macbook.local" into "mymacbook"

thankyou for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

[Prompt Magic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/)

> Why stick with the standard boring shell prompt when you can easily make it colorful and more informative? In this tip, Daniel Robbins will show you how to get your shell prompt just the way you like it, as well as how to dynamically update your X terminal's title bar.